# XSLFO page-break if current page is not empty

Tags: pdf, xslt, xsl-fo

I am using **xslfo** to generate PDFs for some time now, but I always came across the question, how to call `<fo:block break-after="page"/>` without generating an empty page? That is, I would like to check if the current page is empty and in that case, not to call `<fo:block break-after="page"/>`?

anyone having a solution to this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add your XSLT stylesheet and/or XSL-FO file - so that we can reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are probably using Apache FOP. This XSL FO:

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="first">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:block>Test</fo:block>
        <fo:block break-after="page"/>
        <fo:block break-after="page"/>
        <fo:block break-after="page"/>
        <fo:block break-after="page"/>
        <fo:block break-after="page"/>
        <fo:block>Test</fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
```

Would render 2 pages in a compliant XSL FO rendering engine. Using RenderX XEP = 2 pages. using FOP 6 pages (which is wrong).

Comment: `page-break-after="always"` can work as well, in my case your answer was better, cheers!